# PMU (Performance Monitor Unit) in ARM 11

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi

How can I use PMU(Performance Monitor Unit) in ARM11 to calculate execution clock cycles of an assembly code?

I am using Raspberry Pi Model B. I am programming it in assembly language (running assembly program as OS), and want to calculate the number of clock cycles it takes to execute my code.

Answer (score 1):

Start from here:
[Performance Monitor Unit example code for ARM11 and Cortex-A/R](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/17587.html)

I've also seen a good resource on some Raspberry Pi dedicated site but have not saved the link. I'll post it if I find it.

Here we go: [Raspberry Pi](http://sandsoftwaresound.net/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-gen-1/performance-counter-kernel-module/)